# python3 - learning about searching, this very simple example does not work right

Tags: python, list, sorting, search, python-3.x

here's the code:

```
def findsort(something, alist):
    for item in alist:
        if item == something:
            return "found"
        else:
            return "not found"

def main():

    print(findsort(6, [3, 6, 1, 8, 11, 14]))

main()
```

for some reason, this doesn't work the way i thought it should work.

when i run this, it will say "not found."  however, if i change the value i want to find to the first item in the list, the 3, it comes back as "found."

i have tried this with strings, and i get the same results.

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could simplify that function to `return "found" if something in alist else "not found"`

Answer (score 5):

Because if in the first iteration the item doesn't match, you go into the else branch returning "not found", thus exiting the loop.

Try this:

```
def findsort(something, alist):
    for item in alist:
        if item == something:
            return "found"
    return "not found"
```

or simply:

```
def findsort(something, alist):
    return "found" if something in alist else "not found"
```

Comment: @Dan D. Please do not truncate other users' posts due to personal preference of coding style. Do revise other users' posts in order to correct typos and the such.

Comment: I agree with you that Dan should rather add comment. On the other hand, the answer goest to a beginner and the information dosage should use the correct size of drops. The removed code actually means: *Use this complicated way to give the name to the unnamed function.*

Comment: thank you for this information.  while i understand that this is not the most efficient way to code, this class was designed for the absolute beginner.  as you can tell, i still have a long way to go before fully understanding something as simple as a for loop.

Comment: You are most welcome. Think about accepting any of these answers, so people stay motivated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

[@hyperboreus pointed out the cause of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13852518/4279) (the `else` branch executing before all items are seen).

To find an item in a **sorted** ("ordered") list you could use [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) that performs binary search (`O(log(n)`) instead of linear search `item in alist` (`O(n)`) e.g., for a million items binary search would require around a couple dozen operations against a million operations for the linear search.

```
from bisect import bisect

findsort = lambda x, L: "found" if L and L[bisect(L,x) - 1] == x else "not found"
```

Comment: True, but this assumes that the list is ordered.

Comment: @John: `findsort` name suggests that the input is sorted but the example list in the question is not sorted. I've made it bold to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah, it is an odd name. Still, +1 for binary search. And sorry, I meant to type "ordered ascending", but I must've spaced.

Comment: thank you, but i am such novice with programming that i can't even begin to get my head 'round what you just wrote.

it looks pretty sweet though. :)